# Convert Front Door Entry Mailbox to a Front & Rear Door Entry Mailbox

Tags: mailbox

I need to convert a regular MEDIUM size STEEL mailbox with only one streetside  entry door to place mail in & to take mail out.  I'm trying to figure out how to remove the backside of the mailbox so I can add a rear door facing the sidewalk. 
 So far I've had no luck finding a MEDIUM size steel mailbox that has both front & rear door entries.

How would I remove the backside of a STEEL mailbox so I can add a rear door?

[image]

Comment: the big question is "why bother?"

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "arts and crafts" questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Where in the world are you ?  Some countries have restrictions about mailboxes, and in other countries anything goes.

Comment: What is medium size to you ?  https://postalpromailboxes.com/product/the-carlton-two-door/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're going to want to do is this:

[image: Double ended car]

That back of the mail box is going to be crimped on in such a way that it can't be removed without cutting the back of the mailbox off.  This would leave sharp edges, so you could round those off and then attempt to re-use the back as a makeshift door, or you could just get another mailbox and use the door from it.

There's several ways you can use the two mailboxes to make one double-ender, so that bit of creativity is up to you.  I'd probably cut the back 40% off of each one and join the fronts to end up with a slightly longer "limo" mailbox.

I see what you mean about finding a "medium" double door box.  They also have [replacement doors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008D70J6W) that are made for bricked in mailboxes that might work for this, but they seem very expensive for what they are.

[image: Maibox door]

Comment: If the "medium" size of the single-door mailbox is the OP's preference then surely a 50/50 cut is preferable; converting to "limo-size" defeats part of the project's motivation.

Answer (score 3):

You probably can't.

Mailboxes must be approved by the US Postal Service.   That would seem to prohibit alterations in the box *proper*.  Shrouding it is ok, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I just made this exact retrofit and the results were excellent.  First I removed the back panel which left the flange of the main portion of the box.  Then I flattened the flange of the main portion of the box with a brass hammer (supporting the inside of the box with a few lengths of 2x4's.  I did not think it flattened as much as I wanted it to be so then I used my Vice Grips to flatten/crimp it further.  I had another mailbox of the same size so I had a donor for the new door.  I drilled out the rivets which held the door to the main portion of the donor mailbox.  Then I placed the donor door on the back of my new mailbox and drilled the holes in the bottom edge of the main portion of the box.  I needed to hold the two layers of metal together with Vice grips when drilling the holes.  Finally I used 1/4" hardware to attach the new door to the back of the mailbox.  I used a screw with a wide head and a nylon lock nut.  The door was initially difficult to close and open so I just needed to make a few adjustments to the shape of the flattened/crimped opening.  The cost of this retrofit was much lower than the alternatives.  Option 1 is QTY 2 of the MEDIUM  size mailboxes which are around $20 each at The Home Depot.  Option 2 is to purchase a mailbox which is specifically designed with a double door, but the only available size is a LARGE and that is around $50 on amazon.com.  Option 3 is the replacement door in the image posted above, but the cost of that replacement door is around $35 on amazon.com.  My retrofit was definitely the best option and it looks great

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement! Thank you for your answer.